# SQLSRV Not Showing in PHP INFO

Tags: sql-server, xampp

I have download and install SQLSRV32.EXE
I have configured php.ini by adding extension

```
[PHP_SQLSRV]
extension = php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
[PHP_PDO_SQLSRV]
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

I also have **ntwdblib.dll** , copy to xampp> apache> bin

and **php_mssql.dll & php_pdo_mssql.dll** , copy to xampp> php> ext

and configuration of the php.ini

```
extension = php_mssql.dll
extension = php_pdo_mssql.dll
```

My apache restart several times,

I use php version 5.5,

xampp 1.8.3

Sql Server 2008 R2 Express

Is there something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

are you using xampp? make sure you load php_pdo_mssql.dll on x86 version
and thread safe version for non IIS
the file name could be like : php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts_x86.dll